# The definition height of a rational point on an elliptic curve which is not in Weierstrass normal form

Tags: elliptic-curves

Assume that $$E:y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$$ is an elliptic curve that is defined over ${\bf{Q}}$ and is expressed in Weierstrass form. Then, the *height* $H(P)$ of a rational point $P=({\frac{a}{b}},{\frac{c}{d}})\in{E({\bf{Q}})}$ is defined to be $$H(P) = {\rm{max}}(|a|,|b|).$$ Can this definition still be used to find the height of rational point of the curves *not* in Weierstrass normal form? Apologies if this is trivial!
I can be more specific. If the elliptic curve is defined over ${\bf Q}$ as $$E:y^2 -y =2(x^3 -x),$$ how can find the height of a rational point on this curve? Do I first convert this curve to Weierstrass form and then use the definition above, or can I use the definition directly?

Comment: What are you going to use the height for?

Comment: Usually the height is $\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)$ where $[x:y:z]$ is an integer point on the projective curve and $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$. It has some good arithmetic meaning because it is $=\prod_v \max(|x|_v,|y|_v,|z|_v)$ which is invariant under $[x:y:z]\to [xr:yr:zr]$ and has a local interpretation. For your point it gives $\max(|a\frac{d}{g}|,|c\frac{b}{g}|)$ where $g=\gcd(b,d)$.

Comment: Somos, the curve is not given in Weierstrass form, so if I want to find the height, can I still use the formula for $H(P)$? I converted the curve to Weierstrass form and got $$E:Y^2 = X^3 -12X + 20.$$ The point $P = ({\frac{a}{b}},{\frac{c}{d}})$ gets transformed to $Q = ({\frac{2(ad-2bc)}{2ad-bc}},{\frac{6bd}{2ad-bc}})$. And the heights $H(P)$ and$H(Q)$ are different. So I was wondering whether it is meaningful to even define $H(P)$ as ${\rm{max}}(|a|,|b|)$.