# On the Diophantine equation $2(x^3 - x) = y^3 - y$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

It started with the following Diophantine equation:

> Find all positive integers $x, y$ such that:
> $$2(x^3 - x) = y^3 - y $$

First we see that $(x,y) = (1,1)$ is a solution.

Consider $x,y \ge2$, we have:
$$y^3-y = (\sqrt[3]{2}x)^3 - 2x <(\sqrt[3]{2}x)^3 - \sqrt[3]{2}x$$
Because $f(x) = x^3-x$ is strictly increasing on $\left[1;+\infty \right)$, we have $y<\sqrt[3]{2}x$. Suppose $y \le \sqrt[3]{2}x-1$. Then:
$$2x^3 - 2x = y^3 - y \le (\sqrt[3]{2}x-1)^3 - (\sqrt[3]{2}x - 1) = 2x^3 -3\sqrt[3]{4}x^2 +2\sqrt[3]{2}x \iff 3\sqrt[3]{4}x^2 \le (2+2\sqrt[3]{2})x $$

Which is false for $x\ge 2$, so $\sqrt[3]{2}x >y > \sqrt[3]{2}x-1$. Since $y$ is an integer, we must have $y = \lfloor \sqrt[3]{2}x \rfloor$. I then plugged in some values of $x$ and got $(x,y) = (4,5)$ and it seemed like $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{2}x \rfloor ^3 - \lfloor \sqrt[3]{2}x \rfloor < 2(x^3-x)$ for $x >4$ but I have no idea whether it's true or not.

How can we prove or disprove the above inequality? (Also, is there a simpler approach to the Diophatine equation?)

Comment: Your diophantine equation is an elliptic curve, hence it is known that there are at most finitely many integral solutions. However, this of course says nothing about the precise number of solutions.

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1768802p11597030), or [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h48955p310052). This is a well known problem, with solutions on the web.

Comment: Moreover, it seems to me that your inequality fails e.g. for x=504 and x=4813.

Comment: @Algebrus It is not of Weiertrass form, which would be $y^2+a_1y+a_2=f(x)$. For the elliptic curve $y^2-y=2(x^3-x)$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568538/the-definition-height-of-a-rational-point-on-an-elliptic-curve-which-is-not-in-w?noredirect=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I do not think that we need a Weierstrass form, it holds for any affine smooth curve of genus $\geq 1$ by Siegel's theorem on integral points (cf. Wikipedia).

Comment: Yes, this is correct, of course.